# Open pojo testing for equals and hashcode

Tags: testing, equals, hashcode, pojo

I am using OpenPojo for testing pojos, i am testing for equals and hashcode too. In the package which has the pojo classes, some classes have both methods and some classes do not. So I am getting test errors.

How can I write a test to check hashcode and equals only if they are present in the class?

Thanks

Comment: Hi all, I did it with taking individual classes in package . For e.g. pojoClass = PojoClassFactory.getPojoClass(ClassName.class);
pojoValidator.runValidation(pojoClass);   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your Tester, you can decide to skip based on which method is missing, however, this does raise a much more important question, which is why would you have just one of those pair implemented?

It will cause a P1 in your production environment that you will have a hard time understanding how it happened.

If those Classes are going to end up in any Hash* collection (HashMap, HashTable, ...etc) or any Set or cached by an external framework (eg Hibernate) you will be in deep trouble because by definition, java says if classes are equal, their hashCode must be equal and if their hashCode is different they can't be equal.

*See:* [Identity Management](https://github.com/oshoukry/openpojo/wiki/Tutorial-5.-Identity-Management)